# How to return an inverse function based on parameters (for formal differentiation)

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, inverse

I want to return a different function for any given parameter in order to later calculate a value of the inverse of that function given the parameter as an indeterminate.

That is, I want, for each $d$, to return $f(d)$ that gives me something of this form: $(f(d))(a)=g(d,a)$, to later formally calculate $(f(d))^{-1}(y)=a$.

What I tried is

```
func[d_]:=Function[{a},g[a,d]]
```

Where 'g' is a function defined earlier. But calling

```
f[y_]:=InverseFunction[func[d]][y]
```

doesn't work, which is what I actually need.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you already looked at the three-argument form of `InverseFunction[]`?

Comment: @J. M. I did look at it, but I haven't tried it, since I know that my function is not injective when the other parameter $d$ is not given, so I assume it won't work.